# Pandas PanelOLS, OLS predictions

Tags: python, pandas

I have built a panel, p from a dataframe, dfi like so

```
p=dfi.to_panel()
```

and p looks like

```
In [1334]: p
Out[1334]:
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 80 (major_axis) x 20 (minor_axis)
Items axis: bid to px
Major_axis axis: 2013-01-02 05:00:00 to 2013-04-29 04:00:00
Minor_axis axis: 02005NAB6 to 893647AP2
```

I built a model like so (model looks reasonable)

```
m=pd.ols(y=p['bid'],x={'px':p['px'],'qty':p['qty']},entity_effects=True, intercept=False)
```

Given new data how do I make predictions?

I can’t even get something like this to work.

```
m.predict(x=dfi) and m.predict(x=dfi.dropna()) both give NaN for all rows.
```

To be a little more helpful I took this from the pandas/stats/tests/test_ols.py

```
y = tm.makeTimeDataFrame()
x = Panel({'x1': tm.makeTimeDataFrame(),
           'x2': tm.makeTimeDataFrame()})

result = ols(y=y, x=x)

pred=result.predict(x=x)
```

when I try this predict I get

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...Omitted...

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/panel.pyc in reindex(self, major, minor, method, major_axis, minor_axis, copy, **kwargs)
    815 
    816     def _reindex_multi(self, items, major, minor):
--> 817         a0, a1, a2 = len(items), len(major), len(minor)
    818 
    819         values = self.values

ValueError: Must specify at least one axis
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why the `predict` method is not working but suspect it's an orientation problem. The trouble is that making a prediction by hand is not easy because you would have to add the fixed effects columns yourself.

Can you add a GitHub issue with potentially a standalone reproduction of the problem (with fake data, that's fine) so that someone can look more into it? I am not able to take a serious look at this at the moment.